# How to run strong Go (baduk) playing program locally?

Tags: go

There are some strong bot-players on KGS (from 4d to 2K).

I saw pachi, ayamc and even gnugo having dan ranks on KGS. I wonder how to  run such a strong bots offline.

I tried gnugo and aya, both programs did not used even 5% of my CPU, made fast moves (about 1/2 sec per move) and played very weak (about 6K, I think). I did not found any options to make them use more CPU.

I tried also to run pachi (over GTP, using gogui). Pachi used 100% (6 cores) of my CPU, a lot of RAM but played on about 4K level. It plays a little bit stronger with gigantic fuseki dictionary, but it does not help much.

So, my question is: Is there way to run strong (2k+) bot locally?

Comment: The strongest bots often require cluster computing, and are not available to most users. However, dan-level bots can surely be bought, e.g. http://www.remi-coulom.fr/CrazyStone/

Comment: @mafu a new release of CrazyStone is soon coming. It's current level is 7dan KGS. And will be available there :http://www.unbalance.co.jp/igo/eng/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get any better free versions. If you purchase a copy of [Crazy Stone](http://www.remi-coulom.fr/CrazyStone/) as mafu suggested it may be stronger. If you like the way those bots play and want an offline version it's probably worth trying it out, as that's the engine that several bots use. However, I say may be stronger because I am not sure that the commercial version is the same as the version run for KGS bots.

I have no experience with Crazy Stone as GnuGo can still regularly beat me.

Comment: There is still should be possibility to run strong gnugo (which has open source). I did not find any option to make it to think more. In my PC it always uses less than 1/2 sec per move (and it is not normal). So, by default it does not actually use any CPU, and even cluster computing could not help him. There should be some option, that makes him stronger. The same for ayamc.

Comment: A new, much stronger version of Crazy Stone was released on May 16. The highest level is advertised to be 7D.